# Error while integrating React Native debugger with react native app (expo)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, debugging

I am trying to integrate my React-Native app(expo) with React Native Debugger. But I am getting the below error:-

**error:-**
[image]

**Please find my code below:-**

**App.js**

```
const App = () => {
  const store =  createStore(reducer,
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-underscore-dangle
      window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__(),
  );
  return (<Provider store={store}>
    <AppNavigator/>
  </Provider>)
}
export default App;
```

**index.js**

```
AppRegistry.registerComponent('ReactNativeDebuggerSetup', () => App);
```